# Getting a list of strings via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get a list of a list of strings in the code below and I am getting an on `select` that reads:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection>'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List>'

```
List<List<string>> rows = (from myRow in data.AsEnumerable()
                            select new List<string> {myRow["FirstName"].ToString(),
                                myRow["LastName"].ToString(),
                                myRow["Department"].ToString(),
                                myRow["Birthdate"].ToString(),
                                myRow["Description"].ToString()
                            });
```

How can I get a list of a list of strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linq is working with enumerables (IEnumerable). You need to convert to a list:

```
List<List<string>> rows = (from myRow in data.AsEnumerable()
                            select new List<string> {myRow["FirstName"].ToString(),
                                myRow["LastName"].ToString(),
                                myRow["Department"].ToString(),
                                myRow["Birthdate"].ToString(),
                                myRow["Description"].ToString()
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks this works.  I actually tried this, but my stupid VS IDE didn't recognize it.  Once I clicked Build, the IDE recognized it.

Comment: You're welcome. Even better than "Thanks": Tick the checkmark! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Method syntax is more concise:

```
List<List<string>> rows = data.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r.ItemArray.Select(o => o + "").ToList())
    .ToList();
```

"half" query syntax:

```
rows = (from row in data.AsEnumerable()
        select row.ItemArray.Select(o => o + "").ToList())
       .ToList();
```

Comment: Shorter yes. But clearer what the result is? Depends. But I like the use of ItemArray.